# What it call if function with same name of outer function?

Tags: php

Ex- 
I want to know the concept of OOP for undermentioned code.

```
class main()
{
    function out(){
                  function out(){
                   } // What this call?
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't redeclare function with same name? will gives you a fatal error?

Comment: why dont you try it yourself?... its not that hard to try it out

Comment: Aside from the fact that it should be `main`, not `main()`; the first `function out(){` will define a class method called `out()`; the second will create a function called `out` in global scope (but only when the class method `out()` is actually called..... and the whole is exceptionally bad and totally contrary to OOP principles - [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/n4C4v)

Comment: I want to know term used for calling these type of functions as we say function overloading,overriding,etc term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you were looking for is shadowing? there is no good answer as this has nothing to do with OOP and your example could have been better.

overloading refers to same identifier different method signature

```
function foo()
function foo($param)
```

overriding refers to a child class defining a method with the same signature as a method in the parent class.

```
class parent {
    public function foo(){return 1;}
}

class child extends parent {
    public function foo(){return 2;}
}
```

shadowing refers to when an identifier in a lower scope has the same identifer as something in a higher scope.

```
$var = 5;
function foo($var){
    echo $var;
}
foo(6); // '6'
echo $var; // '5'
```